# dpkg: invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql

I have read a number of the posts here and they all state to run the following commands:

1. Apt-get -f remove ****
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get upgrade
4. apt-get -f install ****

I have seen these in various order etc, and none are resolving, my issue. No matter what I try I get:

```
 apt-get -f install mysql-server                              Reading package 
lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 53.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
(Reading database ... 83134 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.29-
0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) 
...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
previous failure.
                   Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
```

I have tried several things over the past week and cannot get this to resolve, any assistance would be appreciated. I did notice the message:

Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

and i have yet to get this configured so I am working on that aspect. Any other assistance will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start` to your question.

Comment: Here is the output...

`sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.`

Comment: I was able to find a solution to this issue after searching for another error in the dialog

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql server:`
 `mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:`
`  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.`

I stumbled onto [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873171) which lead me to [this old thread](http://www.linux-archive.org/debian-user/108744-mysql-fails-install-after-aptitude-purge-mysql-server-purge-unused.html) which contained the answer I so desperately needed. I had to run 
`dpkg -S etc/mysql` in order to get the information and found mysql-common was still installed and causing headaches for me.

Comment: I then ran `aptitude purge mysql-server --purge-unused` to clean the files. This worked like a charm. Hope this solution helps someone else down the road!

Comment: I got this error because my VM didn't have enough memory and no swap either

Answer (score 40):

Solution from Titanicx worked for me. Ran

```
dpkg -S etc/mysql
```

to see that mysql-common was the problem. Removed MySQL completely:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried many other solutions and many other steps.  Finally, the key to the problem!

Comment: What is dpkg -S?  Mine doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before. MySQL Daemon will be started just right after configuring the package, and if there is any errors in MySQL configuration or problems with accessing data directory, then the job will fail.

Checking MySQL error log on `/var/log/mysql/error.log` can help you in this case.

In my case, there was an access error caused by **apparmor**:

```
150131 19:38:23  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

And it just solved by editing appropriate apparmor file.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had `/tmp` sym-linked elsewhere and Apparmor didn't like it.

Editing `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp` and adding the real path to `/tmp` fixed it and allowed MySQL to start successfully.

([Source of inspiration](/q/442536))

Answer (score 0):

If nothing at all helps try [this one](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,577216,577216). I downloaded the deb package from the mysql site. then

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.13-debian6.0-i686.deb 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Big thanks to Ingo.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was very simple

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Got:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.38-1~dotdeb.0) ...
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/mysql missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
mysql start/running, process 21373
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like no need to do all these purges and removals.
All you need to do is to remove the server, and execute:

```
rm /etc/mysql/ -R
```

And then install the server.

The idea was from the external link referenced from the answer at this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/a/448249/109764

Answer (score 0):

Clean your os from all mysql install and add ppa    from there https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6

Comment: Can you please explain how to add the PPA, and how to install these packages?