# Mysql 5.5 reinstallation 12.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql, error-handling

I had a broken installation of mariadb over mysql 5.5. For hours i have tried to reinstall mysql with the usage of apt-get - tried to purge, remove etc everything mysql related. Uninstalled php aswell. Apache got reinstalled too. Every single install was throwing errors during mysql-server configuration. I finally managed to perform a succesfull installation from deb package from website. I ran this after the package was installed:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` Installtion failure part:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems     prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up libmariadbclient18 (10.0.8+maria-1~precise) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
```

All right, so I ran `sudo dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.5` and got

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
```

If we try to run `mysql` we get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Which guides me back to my.cnf manipulation and mysql reinstallation. Goddamn closed error circle.

I have tried every solution related to mysql installation I have found. Really running out of options here, reinstalling and configuring ubuntu would be easier and faster. Any feedback appreciated.

EDIT: One notice - why am I prompted for mysql admin password 3 times during an installation?

Comment: try to install webmin by $wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.670_all.deb then $dpkg -i webmin_1.670_all.deb then $apt-get -f install and connect though web by https://yourserverip:10000 and from servers part, try to connect to MySQL

Comment: I installed it, that doesnt change anything. I can't start mysql from webmin because it just tries "service mysql start" which isnt going to work.

Comment: Are you sure mariadb is not still installed/running and preventing mysql from claiming its default port?

Comment: checked my entire package list, didn't find anything with mariadb in it's name. Although mysql now installs something from mariadb by default, which confuses me a bit.

Comment: To close voters, this question has been perfectly on topic at the time it was asked, so I'm voting to leave open. See also https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16132/please-dont-flag-old-questions-as-eol

Comment: Unless [Lonnie Best's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/539199) is the solution--and in this particular case, I am not sure if it is--then I believe Avinash Raj's answer *almost* managed to provide the correct solution, and that it merely didn't advise to remove all the relevant MySQL packages. Even if that is *not* the solution, this problem manifests in the same way as [the one in that question](https://askubuntu.com/q/261250) (see the top answer for why I think removing more packages would have helped). I don't think this is off-topic--not even as *no repro*--but I belive it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands to completely remove the unconfigured `mysql-server-5.5`,`mysql-server`
 packages,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-5.5
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server
```

Then install it again by running,

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: tried that hours ago. Ends up in same spot "start: Job failed to start"

Comment: Now try my edit.

Comment: still the same ;/ Would you have any idea why am i asked 3 times for mysql password?\

Comment: post the output of `sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-5.5`.

Comment: (Reading database ... 352586 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.5 ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-server-5.5 ...
dpkg: warning: while removing mysql-server-5.5, directory '/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5' not empty so not removed.
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...

Comment: try to delete the folder `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5` manually by running `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5` and then try the above command.

Comment: output is the same without the warning

Comment: please post the output in pastebin and then provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KRw3prNj

Comment: yes you successfully removed `mysql-server-5.5` package  now run the next commands.

Comment: Ah, didnt'get your point. Here it is. http://pastebin.com/eqf86RbN

Comment: did you run `sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server
` command?

Comment: yes, the output is in the first pastebin

Comment: you run only `sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-5.5` command after that you have to run `sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server` so that it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason this happened was that the root partition was full. Check to see how much free space you have on your root partition:

```
df -h
```

If you are out of space, see what's taking up that space:

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu ; sudo ncdu /
```