# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) when installing libmariadbclient-dev in ubuntu 14.0.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I have been trying to install mariadb on Ubuntu 14.04

I installed it some 4 months back, following a tutorial from [mariadb website](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=netinch&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty&version=10.1).

I typed the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://mirror.netinch.com/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

And the installation failed leaving my system in a mess.

When I try to install `libmariadbclient-dev` I get the following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmariadbclient-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 214 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,279 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,362 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 286477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.47-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmariadbclient-dev (5.5.47-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.47-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/aclocal/mysql.m4', which is also in package mysql-common 5.7.11-1ubuntu14.04
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.47-1ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get install -f` as suggested in many posts but to no avail.
I have also tried suggestions in [how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-14-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548792/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-14-10?rq=1)

Comment: There's an implicit conflict between `mysql-common` and `libmariadbclient-dev `. Do you really need the latter? `*-dev` packages are not necessary to run software from packages. If you need it, try to remove `mysql-common` first. If you want help with the installation of `mariadb-server` you need to include the verbatim output of `apt-get` so people can see the issue and help you.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for your suggestions. Though coming late as I had already resolved the issue.